# Jenkins workspace location

Tags: git, jenkins

If I clone a github project in jenkins, where does the project exactly gets cloned in the Jenkins server? What is the exact location of Github project in jenkins server?

Answer (score 2):

When you run a Jenkins job with Git SCM, the Git repository will be cloned inside the job specific workspace, which can be found at ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${JOB_NAME}

Comment: And ${JENKINS_HOME} will most likely be `/var/lib/jenkins`

Comment: Is this (Jenkins_Home) is not the 'Home directory' in Manage Jenkins -> configure system?

Comment: Yes, so inside that directory on your Jenkins server there will be a workspace directory, inside of which there will be job specific directories, and your cloned Git repo will be inside of the job specific directory